# graph coloring and NP completeness

Tags: algorithm, graph, np-complete

I am having trouble understanding the NP completeness of graph coloring.

If I assume a greedy coloring strategy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Greedy_coloring) with DFS, then I seem to be able to color graphs optimally. Could anyone help me with a counter example?

To be clear, let all nodes be colored -1. Color the start node 1. Proceed in a DFS traversal coloring every node with the minimum integer that is not already assigned to its neighbors. When would this fail to optimally color the graph?

Comment: Did you even read the Wikipedia page? It says, _"The quality of the resulting coloring depends on the chosen ordering. . . On the other hand, greedy colorings can be arbitrarily bad; for example, the crown graph on n vertices can be 2-colored, but has an ordering that leads to a greedy coloring with n/2 colors."_

Comment: I did read it and I wouldn't ask if I understood. I tried the crown graph in the adjacent picture and on the link that takes you to the "crown graph" article with different DFS orderings. I understand that a BFS ordering will fail. I didn't find a DFS ordering that would.

Comment: @TedHopp: that bad greedy coloring of the crown graph cannot be generated from a *DFS* greedy coloring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS greedy coloring will certainly fail on some graphs.  The way to come up with a counterexample is to try to write a proof that DFS will color optimally.  The part of the proof that you can't quite get to work is the hint for coming up with a counterexample.